# What's equivalent of BasicTeX in Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, latex

TeX Live is a large distribution of LaTeX. BasicTeX is a subset of TeX Live for users who do not want to download the full TeX Live. Is there any equivalent of BasicTeX in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TeX Live is divided into several packages in Ubuntu. If you don't want the whole thing (and indeed most users don't need the whole thing), install [texlive-base](http://packages.ubuntu.com/texlive-base) [image: Install texlive-base], which is similar in size to BasicTeX. You may want to install [texlive-latex-recommended](http://packages.ubuntu.com/texlive-latex-recommended) [image: Install texlive-latex-recommended] and [texlive-fonts-recommended](http://packages.ubuntu.com/texlive-fonts-recommended) [image: Install texlive-fonts-recommended] as well as support for the language(s) you write in (texlive-lang-…).